# DataType.fromJson() Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the JSON string 'int' to a data type

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Trying to create a StructType from a JSON file to be used as schema for creating a dataframe.

JSON structure:

```
    {
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [
    {
    "name" : "LocationID",
    "type" : "int",
    "nullable" : false,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "Boroght",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "zone",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "serviceZone",
    "type" : "string",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
```

Reading JSON file and creating StructType:

```
val schemaSource =  Source.fromFile(url.getFile).mkString
val schemaFromJson = DataType.fromJson(schemaSource).asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the JSON string 'int' to a data type.
```

Not sure if it's the JSON structure or what to change there.

Comment: The type should be `integer` instead of `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of `LocationID` should be `integer` not `int`.

Comment: Using integer, but still getting the same error